# Materialze collapsible not woking inside ng-switch

Tags: angularjs, materialize

- I am trying to inject different sections on button click, on the same page.
- For that, I am using `ng-switch` directive of angularJs.
- It's working fine, on button click, I can change my sections.

But the problem is when I add materialize controls, then they don't work inside `ng-switch` directive.
Why is this happening?

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mayankBisht/ADukg/16496/)

Answer (score 0):

you are using jquery material and this is normal behavior/ try angular material. but keep in mind that ng-switch and ng-if are so called structural directives. and theirs scopes may mess up smth. sometimes you can use ng-hide to avoid that strange behavior

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the answer. Actually, I have different pages, and I want to inject them, whenever a user clicks on their links.